# How to combine kableExtra with latex footer?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am trying to knit the following RMarkdown to pdf:

````
---
title: 'Title'
params:
  set_title: 'title report'
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \lhead{}
- \chead{}
- \rhead{Semester Graduation Report `r params$set_title`}
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r, include =FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F, message = F, warning = F)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '-')
```


```{r, results='asis'}
kable(mtcars, format = 'latex', longtable = T, booktabs = T, caption='This is a caption' ) %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "something"=2, "something else"=2)) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))
```

```{r}
kable(mtcars)
```
````

However, it retrieves and error

> ! Missing $ inserted.
>    
>                  $
>   l.239 \end{document}

I've noticed that if I delete the `header-includes` it works fine, but I would rather not have to drop the header. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `kableExtra` not to load any LaTeX packages by setting the global option `kableExtra.latex.load_packages` to be `FALSE` before you load this package and put in necessary LaTeX packages by yourself.

You can refer to the `Getting Started` Section of the package [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf). (Please forgive me for the typo in the illustrated code...)

In this case, you do

````
---
title: 'Title'
params:
  set_title: 'title report'
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \lhead{}
- \chead{}
- \rhead{Semester Graduation Report `r params$set_title`}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r, include =FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F, message = F, warning = F)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)
options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
options(knitr.kable.NA = '-')
```
````